# Create index.md files in _posts and its subdirectories

Tags: html, jekyll

I’m looking for a method to categorize post entities (*.md or *.html in `_post`) based on a specific hierarchy.

For example, I want my directory structure like this:

```
_posts
-- Category A
---- Subcategory a
-- Category B
---- Subcategory b
---- Subcategory c
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7sxg.png)

What I’ve tried is adding `permalink: /:path.html` in `_config.yml` file; then I got the following `_site` materials after jekyll build.

```
_site
-- 2024-01-01-post-01.md
-- Category A
---- 2024-01-02-post-02.md
---- Subcategory a
------ 2024-01-03-post-03.md
------ 2024-01-04-post-04.md
-- Category B
---- 2024-01-05-post-05.md
---- Subcategory b
---- Subcategory c
------ 2024-01-06-post-06.md
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48CNs.png)

Pretty looks nice though, BUT there is no index.md file in each directory (also including root directory). So when I access to URL such as `localhost:4000/Category%20A`, blank page appears on my web browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbcZY.png)

I want a specific html layout to be applied to all of the category paths (`/`, `/Category A`, `/Category A/Subcategory a`, and so on.). To do so, it seems necessary to place index.md files inside every subdirectory.

Is there any simple solution? (It's my first Q&A post, so I'm not permitted to upload image directly yet. sorry about that.)